# Four-digit string number to two-digit string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, slice

I want to slice a string (which is a four-digit number), but if the string start with a 0, then I get only the second letter from the string

The code:

```
 for i in range(0,b):
     data2['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR2'][i]=data2['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR'][i][0:2]
```

and the results:

```
CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR   CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR2
    1920                         19
    0150                          1
```

How could I solve this probem

Comment: You haven't supplied all of the code.  Your code as it is should give you exactly what you seek.  You are using an `int()` somewhere, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use int()

```
for i in range(0,b):
    data2['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR2'][i]=int(data2['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR'][i][0:2])
```

Comment: Maybe there is an misunderstanding: I haven't written but I do not need an integer, but I need a string like this: '0125' --> '01

Comment: So you can convert it back to string, or it would be easier to take jezrael's solution

Comment: @RolandSzarka, That directly conflicts with your question `but if the string start with a 0, then I get only the second letter from the string`. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54092861/edit) to clarify.

Comment: That doesn't conflict.  He's telling us that he gets '1' instead of '01'.  His goal is '01'.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing with `str` and then remove `0` from left side by [`lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
df['new'] = df['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR'].str[:2].str.lstrip('0')
#better performance if larger data and no NaNs
#df['new_str'] = [x[:2].lstrip('0') for x in df['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR']]
```

If need integers, but double `00` return `0` only cast instead stripping:

```
df['new'] = df['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR'].str[:2].astype(int)
```

Data:

```
df['new_str'] = df['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR'].str[:2].str.lstrip('0')
df['new_int'] = df['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR'].str[:2].astype(int)
print (df)
  CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR2 new_str  new_int
0                      0032                         34                0
1                      1920                         19      19       19
2                      0150                          1       1        1
```

Comment: Maybe there is an misunderstanding: I haven't written but I do not need an integer, but I need a string like this:
'0125' --> '01'

Comment: @RolandSzarka - It is my first solution, `df['new'] = df['CLIENTBANKTEAORMANUAL_STR'].str[:2].str.lstrip('0')`